# How can I use seshat on normal images as input in seshat (mathematical expression recognition library in C++)?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, ocr, mathematical-expressions

I have compiled seshat but it requires input in inkml or scgink format. As the code is in cpp I am unable to understand. How can I use this work (seshat) on normal math images?

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Note: I have seen other answers on stack overflow regarding this but I was not able to get them

If any python work is there (Because I am only familiar with python)

or is there any way I could convert normal image to the format that seshat accepts

Comment: @anthonybrice can you please help here!!

Comment: Did a quick look-up for `inkML` file generator in Python and didn't found one. I think the most obvious way of approaching this problem is to `skeltonize` your input image and convert the lines to equidistant list of points, which in turn can be written to an XML file(which essentially is what inkML is all about).

Comment: Other options in case would be to tweak the library you are using to inject the list of points directly bypassing the inkML parsing step.

Comment: Thanks @ZdaR for your help!!